# Bootstrap Navbar Link Toggler Not Showing

Tags: html, toggle, navbar

EDIT 9-10-19: I gave the img tag a class of "logo" and moved the inline styles to the seperate style sheet, the Navbar links don't collapse to a toggle icon still.

I've been styling a bootstrap navbar with some success, but for some reason when I reduce the page size the navbar links don't collapse into a Toggle Icon, they just disappear.

I want the navbar links to disapear if the page gets too small but be replaced with a button that can be toggled to reveal the navbar links.

I've done a lot of looking and most of the problem solutions I've found involve making sure the div ids match, I'm pretty sure mine do, please help!

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light">
<div class="container-fluid">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/darkiddlogostandalone.png" height="57px" width="200px"></a>

<button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive">
                                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

<div class="navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Illustration</a>
            </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Animation</a>
            </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

I just want the links to condense into the toggle button on the right.

Answer (score 0):

SO to answer my own question (sort of)

I went back to an earlier version of this bootstrap template I made when the hamburger toggler was working, and meticulously added the logo and styled the navbar over again because I found that reverting back to old stylesheets seemed to allow the hamburger to show up.

I found that styling using the bootstrap classes can be hit or miss, so I gave my logo img tag a class of "logo" and then went into the style sheet and

```
`position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
z-index: -1;`
```

I don't know if that's overkill to keep the logo on the top left of the fluid container that is the navbar, I was watching this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rgukBRi1CSU&t=594s
And although it was hard to understand the gentleman, he mentions getting rid of bg-light and navbar-light in order to make his navbar forrest green, I just wanted grey so I removed bg-light and added a class called "navback" and used that to style the background color...`<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light sticky-top navback">`

```
`.navback {
background-color: #A8A8A8;
```

}`

My logo was huge, and I was having a hard time getting it to reliably resize, so I made it 190x54px and that seemed to remove the need for styling it's size, and I think the logo itself was causing the problem, for whatever reason my styling of the navbar and the logo was getting in the way of the collapsing of the navbar links into the hamburger toggle button, but the above changes seemed to remedy the situation.